# Linux server to send and receive from RS-232 using socat

Tags: linux, terminal, ethernet, rs232, socat

I'm trying to bench test a configuration where a Linux server will send and receive RS-232 data from a Black Box RS-232 to Ethernet converter. I've followed [this example](http://techtinkering.com/2013/04/02/connecting-to-a-remote-serial-port-over-tcpip/). I've configured `ser2net.conf` on my machine connected to the serial port with:

```
3333:raw:0:/dev/ttyS0:115200,8DATABITS,NONE,1STOPBIT
```

On my remove server I'm running in one terminal:

```
sudo socat -d pty,link=/dev/ttyV0,waitslave tcp:192.168.1.55:719
```

In another terminal I'm running:

```
screen /dev/ttyV0 115200
```

which is followed by:
`[screen is terminating]` and the `socat` process dying in the other terminal.

Does anyone see a problem with my configuration or have a better solution?